# JBoss Tools - .xhtml Indentation

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I added JBoss tools to my project in an attempt to add some JSF 2 bean aware content completion. I'm really happy with how that's going. I'm using Eclipse for Java EE Juno service release 1 Build id: 20120920-0800. I have the CDI, dynamic web module, Java, javascript, JSF 2.1, JAX-RS 1.1 JBoss Maven Integration 1.0 and JPA 2.0 facets installed on this project.

But now when I use ctrl-i in Eclipse to "align" everything properly my .xhtml files collapse the first layer of tags beneath the  tag. I really don't like how it looks, and I don't think it will be standard if other people join the project. Here's what it does.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Invalid user name or password.</h2>

        <p>Please enter a user name or password that is authorized to access this
            application. For this application, this means a user that has been
            created in the <code>file</code> realm and has been assigned to the
            <em>group</em> of <code>TutorialUser</code>.</p>
        <p><a href="faces/index.xhtml">Return to login page</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

becomes the below chunk after I use ctrl-i

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Login Error</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Invalid user name or password.</h2>

    <p>
    Please enter a user name or password that is authorized to access this
    application. For this application, this means a user that has been
    created in the
    <code>file</code>
    realm and has been assigned to the <em>group</em> of
    <code>TutorialUser</code>
    .
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="faces/index.xhtml">Return to login page</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice how  and  tags are both lacking a level of indentation. Any ideas on how to fix this or where to configure it would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue in, both in Eclipse Luna without JBoss Tools and Kepler with JBossTools.

Comment: I did not :( I use IntelliJ now. Though this indentation style seems to be popular there too.